# Getting sections that will be run in Catch

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test

The Catch2 unit test framework allows you to have [test sections](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#test-cases-and-sections). From the docs:

```
TEST_CASE( "vectors can be sized and resized", "[vector]" ) {

    std::vector<int> v( 5 );

    REQUIRE( v.size() == 5 );
    REQUIRE( v.capacity() >= 5 );

    SECTION( "resizing bigger changes size and capacity" ) {
        v.resize( 10 );

        REQUIRE( v.size() == 10 );
        REQUIRE( v.capacity() >= 10 );
    }
    SECTION( "resizing smaller changes size but not capacity" ) {
        v.resize( 0 );

        REQUIRE( v.size() == 0 );
        REQUIRE( v.capacity() >= 5 );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to identify **up front**, at the time of `testCaseStarting()`, what is the list of `SECTION`s that the particular run? As an example, given:

```
TEST_CASE("a", "[tag]") {
    SECTION("b") {
    }

    SECTION("c") {
        SECTION("d") { }
        SECTION("e") { }
    }
}
```

I want some way to get `{b}` for the first run, `{c, d}` for the second, and `{c, e}` for the third. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. `SECTION` expands into [`INTERNAL_CATCH_SECTION`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/include/internal/catch_section.h) which is just an `if` statement creating `SectionInfo` class instance
:

```
   #define INTERNAL_CATCH_SECTION( ... ) \
    if( Catch::Section const& INTERNAL_CATCH_UNIQUE_NAME( catch_internal_Section ) = Catch::SectionInfo( CATCH_INTERNAL_LINEINFO, __VA_ARGS__ ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not, especially since sections can be "dynamic" in that they can be hidden behind extra ifs, be run inside a loop and so on.